# Laravel model where function

Tags: php, laravel

I try to retrive data from database in laravel model, but my sql is wrong. I dont know why where dont work, set only keys without values.

```
        $passwordReset = PasswordReset::where([
            ['email', $request->get('email')],
            ['token', $request->get('token')]
            ])->toSql();

Array
(
    [token] => TCjM8BZXjLV1YfikyFDjeUwZMUmS5w5r88rEYOMC8XmkET779kjCQEkM9w1u
    [email] => mail@example.com
)
```

select * from `password_resets` where (`email` = ? and `token` = ?)

```
    print_r($request->json()->all());
```

Comment: `toSql()` will convert your query builder to the sql statement, I think you need to replace `toSql()` with `get()`

Comment: yes I know about it, I changed it especially to debug the query because nothing from the database returned and I noticed that where there should be value question marks

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: Read about **prepared statements** in mysql, you will get why the question marks are there

Answer (score 2):

use `->get()->toArray();`

instead of `toSql()`

The first one will output your data in array format the second one will output the mysql query.

Comment: `toArray()` is superfluous. Laravel was built to work with Collections

Comment: Yes agree just added it for formatting the output into an array.

Comment: Thanks for ask :) i need to reload my laravel server and all work fine ! :)